# Infinite loop while catching an exception

Tags: java, exception, while-loop, try-catch, infinite-loop

I'm trying to get an integer from System.in and I want to catch eventual errors. This is the code:

```
int dim;
boolean done = false;

while(!done)
  {
     try
     {
        dim = in.nextInt();
        done=true;
     }
     catch(InputMismatchException e)
     {
        System.out.println("I need an integer");
     }
  }
```

The result i'm getting is an infinite loop of the error string. What i'm doing wrong? Am I trying to catch the wrong exception?

Comment: You're right, I added the boolean value after I copied the code in a hurry, of course when declared done is false.

Comment: Why the try block isn't repeated then?

Comment: Did you set up a Scanner ? If you did please include it in the code.

Comment: I did, and it ask for input the first time. I found the answer in the API docs. Thanks!

Comment: i just found the exact answer: When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method. did you get it from here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: You should post the solution (as an answer to this), it could be useful to someone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method."[Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: Thanks Faraz! (in this case I created a string for the Scanner.next() and then parsed for an integer, changing the catch to the appropriate exception).